# $R$ is a com. ring with identity. $char(R)=p\in \mathbb{P}$. $a,b\in R$. Prove: $\forall 0\leq n\in \mathbb{Z}; (a\pm b)^{p^n} = a^{p^n} \pm b^{b^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$R$ is a commutative ring with identity. $char(R)=p$ where $p$ is a prime number. If $a,b\in R$, then prove that $\forall 0\leq n\in \mathbb{Z}; (a\pm b)^{p^n} = a^{p^n} \pm b^{b^n}$. 
What do you think about using the induction? It may be solved that way.

Comment: Hint: Use Binomial theorem

Comment: every sentence has "p" as a coefficient but the first and last ones

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you both, esp. @313 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a fixed $n$, and use the Binomial Theorem $(a+b)^{p^n}$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{p^n} \binom{p^n}{k} a^{p^n-k}b^{k}$. Notice that the binomial coefficient is divisible by $p^n$ for each $1\le k\le p^n-1$, so each of these coefficients is divisible by $p$. $R$ is of characteristic $p$, so all of these terms are zero and $(a+b)^{p^n} = a^{p^n} + b^{p^n}$. A similar result holds for the conjugate case.

Comment: I had already solved it, but not posted any answer. Anyways, thanks for the work.